# How to stop Emacs (ESS+R) opening a new window in debug mode?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

ess-13.05 opens a new window within the frame when debugging. nice, but i already have a separate frame for my code (and that frame uses Evil, which is why I want it in a separate frame). if i kill the window (C-x 0) then next-stepping through the code re-opens the window in the current frame. So how to stop ESS from doing a C-x 3 on the frame with the debug prompt: Browse[2]> ?

Comment: ESS does pop-to-buffer. See the documentation of `display-buffer`. You might find a way to instruct emacs to open ESS debug buffers in a separate frame. In debug mode `ess-debug-mode` variable is t. Otherwise a custom var should be added to ESS, similar to `ess-help-own-frame`

Comment: How do you identify your code frame?